# Is it possible to change the seed of a random generator in NumPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, random-seed

Say I instantiated a random generator with

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
```

and I want to change its seed. Is it possible to update the seed of the generator instead of instantiating a new generator with the new seed?

I managed to find that you can see the state of the generator with `rng.__getstate__()`, for example in this case it is

```
{'bit_generator': 'PCG64', 
 'state': {'state': 274674114334540486603088602300644985544, 
 'inc': 332724090758049132448979897138935081983}, 
 'has_uint32': 0, 
 'uinteger': 0}
```

and you can change it with `rng.__setstate__` with arguments as printed above, but it is not clear to me how to set those arguments so that to have the initial state of the rng given a different seed. Is it possible to do so or instantiating a new generator is the only way?

Comment: It isn't really that hard to replace references to `np.random` with `rng`.

Comment: What's wrong with `rng.__setstate__(np.random.default_rng(seed=other_seed).__getstate__())` ?

Comment: The problem is that you are creating a new generator inside the __setstate__ function, I don't want to instantiate any new generator if possible

Comment: Yes, but so what? You could go spelunking in [the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/random/_generator.pyx) to find out how the seed 42 translates into the state 274674114334540486603088602300644985544 and do it directly, but that seems like a lot of effort for no obvious reason.

Comment: instantiating new generators is expensive (1 second for 3000 call to the function), if you need to do it a lot of times but you want to generate values just from the updated generator I think it's useful if it's possible to do something like that

Comment: @Tortar that's alarmingly slow and does not match my own experience. On my machine it's on the order of microseconds: `%timeit np.random.default_rng(139580735987294)` yields  `7.61 µs ± 58.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)`. Of course I'm also on a high-spec machine, but still. Did you actually benchmark your code and find that creating `Generator` instances was a bottleneck? Why are you creating the same generator thousands of times anyway?

Comment: ops, sorry it's actually 30000 calls `import timeit  a = timeit.timeit("np.random.default_rng(seed=10)", "import numpy as np", number=30000)

print(a)`

Comment: Yes, this does not seem all that slow to me. What on earth are you doing that you care about these microseconds?

Comment: It's just a curiosity driven question :-) Clearly changing so many times the rng is at least a bit strange-non sensical but still I wanted to find out if there was a way through this

Comment: There is, but you'd just have to figure out what it does [in here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f30af6acdaa8f5b6b00eddaf45c9b4c1911192cb/numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx#L190-L215). It's also more fragile than just creating a new rng to copy its state, because the latter way would presumably continue working even if numpy changed the implementation detail of the underlying bit generator.

Comment: If you want to use a MT19937 BitGenerator instead, these are possible to reseed (just by calling seed again). Though, the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html#numpy.random.seed) say that "_The best practice is to not reseed a BitGenerator, rather to recreate a new one. This method is here for legacy reasons._"

Comment: mmmh indeed that generator is the one of the random module which has a function to reseed, anyway thank you @wim for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**N.B.** The other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74474377/2954547) is better. Use that one, not this one.

---

This is maybe a silly hack, but one solution is to create a *new* RNG instance using the desired new seed, then replace the state of the existing RNG instance with the state of the new instance:

```py
import numpy as np

seed = 12345

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
x1 = rng.normal(size=10)

rng.__setstate__(np.random.default_rng(seed).__getstate__())
x2 = rng.normal(size=10)

np.testing.assert_array_equal(x1, x2)
```

However this isn't much different from just replacing the RNG instance.

Edit: To answer the question more directly, I don't think it's possible to replace the seed without constructing a new `Generator` or `BitGenerator`, unless you know how to correctly construct the state data for the particular `BitGenerator` inside your `Generator`. Creating a new RNG is fairly cheap, and while I understand the conceptual appeal of not instantiating a new one, the only alternative here is to post a feature request on the Numpy issue tracker or mailing list.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question, because it's also "instantiating a new generator". And I've already asked for clarification on that point in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

A Numpy call like `default_rng()` gives you a [`Generator`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) with an implicitly created [`BitGenerator`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.BitGenerator.html).  The difference between these is that a `BitGenerator` is the low-level method that just knows how to generate uniform `uint32`s, `uint64`s, and `double`s.  The `Generator` can then take these and turn them into other distributions.

As you noticed you can use `__getstate__` but this is designed for the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module and not really for what you're using it for.

You're better off accessing the [`bit_generator`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.bit_generator.html) directly.  Which means you don't need to use any dunder methods.

The following code still uses `default_rng` but this means the `BitGenerator` could change in the future so I need a call to `type` to reseed.  You'd probably be better off following the second example which uses an explicit `BitGenerator`.

```
import numpy as np

seed = 42

rng = np.random.default_rng()

# get the BitGenerator used by default_rng
BitGen = type(rng.bit_generator)

# use the state from a fresh bit generator
rng.bit_generator.state = BitGen(seed).state

# generate a random float
print(rng.random())
```

outputs `0.7739560485559633`.  If you're happy fixing the `BitGenerator` you can avoid the call to `type`, e.g.:

```
rng = np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64())

rng.bit_generator.state = np.random.PCG64(seed).state

rng.random()
```

which outputs the same value.

Comment: This is nicer than my answer! Interestingly, you can't assign to `rng.bit_generator` directly. I guess there's some internal state in the `Generator` itself that would get messed up if you swapped out the bit generators dynamically.

Comment: @shadowtalker the `Generator` does some magic [behind the scenes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6a2bc601b24a414fe8f4a17493e9b344dc547096/numpy/random/_generator.pyx#L196) to keep things fast.  note that creating a generator is very cheap, and the rest of the API is designed with this in mind.  i.e. you fork off multiple `Generators` from one [`SeedSequence`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.SeedSequence.html) rather than the usage implied by OPs question

Comment: Perhaps this is an XY question and the real answer is "use `SeedSequence` to pre-create a lot of `Generator`s".

Comment: @shadowtalker maybe, difficult to tell from the question!  I added that comment in the hope that users of this site get pointed to relevant parts of the docs / API